# Create docker file for spring cloud config server

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, docker, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to build docker image for my config server.
These are the steps which I have followed:

- Open https://start.spring.io/  and added config-server as a dependancies. then downloaded the project.
- Added `@EnableConfigServer` annotation in
  `demo\src\main\java\com\example\demo\DemoApplication.java`
- Added below code in `demo\src\main\resources\application.properties`

`server.port=8888  spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/mygitusername/configserverdata.git`

When I started config server using command `mvn spring-boot:run` on local, It's working fine.

Now I want to create docker image for my config server. for this I get this docker file from [here](https://github.com/hyness/spring-cloud-config-server).

```
FROM maven:alpine
MAINTAINER hyness <hyness@freshlegacycode.org>

EXPOSE 8888
COPY . /Demo/
WORKDIR /Demo/
RUN mvn package
VOLUME /config
WORKDIR /
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar",\
            "/Demo/target/Demo.jar",\
            "--server.port=8888",\
            "--spring.config.name=application"]
```

When I execute `docker build -t spring-cloud-config-server .` it says BUILD Failure with this reason

> The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no
>   POM in this directory (/demo). Please verify you invoked Maven from
>   the correct directory.

Please help me to create correct docker file for my config server.

It might be a silly question, But I need to specify `mvn spring-boot:run` in Dockerfile as well.

I've just started learning docker.

Comment: Could you confirm that pom file is present in the current directory (in other words dockerfile and pom in the same dir)?

Comment: I think the issue is in directory layout. You can replace endpoint with " ls /Demo" command and check that pom is in the correct dir. The second strange thing is in error message "/demo" instead of "/Demo", so it would be nice to rename "/Demo" into "/demo" in your Dockerfile.

Comment: @i.bondarenko: From where Do I need to `/Demo` as it is 3 times in DockerFile. Now I moved the dockerfile in same directory for pom file.   for your reference Please open link  https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6mdK.png

Comment: Just use demo instead of Demo in all commands.
Is the situation changed after moving the DockerFile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just built the application and it works fine with this Dockerfile and dirs layout (have alook at "COPY ./demo /demo/") :

```
FROM maven:alpine
MAINTAINER hyness <hyness@freshlegacycode.org>

EXPOSE 8888
COPY ./demo /demo/
WORKDIR /demo/
RUN mvn package
VOLUME /config
WORKDIR /
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar",\
            "/demo/target/demo.jar",\
            "--server.port=8888",\
            "--spring.config.name=application"]
$ tree
.
├── demo
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           ├── java
│           │   └── com
│           │       └── example
│           │           └── demo
│           │               └── DemoApplication.java
│           └── resources
│               └── application.properties
└── Dockerfile
```

Comment: Image was build successfully. But when I tried to run it using docker compose, It is saying `Unable to access jarfile /demo/target/demo.jar`

Comment: Probably name of the jar is demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: Use the same name of the jar as you have in local target/ after mvn build. In my case it is demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: If it is not working do following: change entrypoint to "sleep 100000" build image with another name let say "spring-cloud-config-server2". Run container with the new image "docker run spring-cloud-config-server2" and after that following command "docker exec -it <CONTAINER_ID> sh". It will give you console to your container and you will be able to run any command or java processes as you want.

Comment: Which command did you run locally as I'm running `mvn spring-boot:run` and no jar file in target folder.

Comment: You should use "mvn package" locally and in the docker build.

Comment: Thanks a lot :).  It worked.   Just one more question, Is there any we can rename jar file? Just reading from [here](http://appsdeveloperblog.com/docker-image-for-spring-cloud-config-server/)

Comment: Just add to pom:
<build> 
   <finalName>my-app</finalName>
 </build>